# Why Python losing some value during computing?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a problem from codeforces using Python. but I got wrong answer then I used C++ and got accepted. although I used same formula for both language. I don't understand my mistake.

Here is the problem link: https://codeforces.com/contest/1371/problem/B
**my Python Solution:**

```
t=int(input())
 
while(t >0):
    t = t-1 
 
    n,m = (input()).split()
    a=int(n)
    b=int(m)
 
    if(a >b ):
        ans= (b+1)*b /2
        print(int (ans))
    else:
        a=a-1
        ans = (a + 1) * a / 2
        print(int (ans+1))
```

**my C++ Solution:**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int q;
    cin>>q;
   while(q--)
    {
        ll a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;

        if(a > b )
        {
            cout<< (b*(b+1))/2<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            a--;
            cout<< (a*(a+1))/2 +1 <<endl;
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

And the test case in which i got wrong answer: 1000000000 818008580

expected: '334569018885812490', found: '334569018885812480'

Comment: Python is dynamically typed language. (a + 1) * a / 2 in C++ is rounded as you are using ints. The Python equivalent may be casting it to a floating value

Comment: Interesting question, I need to fire my python to check your codes :)

Comment: I am a beginner dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to precision loss in this expression:

```
ans = (b + 1) * b / 2
```

In the new Python `/` is a float division, and the number is too large to fit into the mantissa. Use integer division instead:

```
ans = (b + 1) * b // 2
```

The same applies to the second expression.